# Dev C++ with OpenCV compile error

Tags: c++, opencv, dev-c++

I'm using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 and OpenCV 2.4.8, I'm also in Windows 7 x86. These are in my compiler setting, `-L"D:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin" -lopencv_highgui248 -lopencv_core248 -lopencv_flann248 -lopencv_gpu248 -lopencv_imgproc248 -lopencv_legacy248 -lopencv_ml248 -lopencv_nonfree248 -lopencv_objdetect248 -lopencv_photo248 -lopencv_video248 -lopencv_ts248.` Every time I compile my simple project, it shows this errors: Compiler:

```
OpenCV
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "D:\VS Projects\WebCam\WebCam\loadimg.cpp" -o "D:\VS Projects\WebCam\WebCam\loadimg.exe"   -g3  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"  -I"D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2"  -I"D:\opencv\build\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" -L"D:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib" -g3 
In file included from D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4854,
                 from D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:47,
                 from D:\VS Projects\WebCam\WebCam\loadimg.cpp:1:
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp: In static member function `static cv::Ptr<_Tp2> cv::Algorithm::create(const std::string&)':
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:3972: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:3972: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp: At global scope:
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:4024: error: got 2 template parameters for `void cv::AlgorithmInfo::addParam(cv::Algorithm&, const char*, cv::Ptr<_Tp2>&, bool, cv::Ptr<_Tp2> (cv::Algorithm::*)(), void (cv::Algorithm::*)(const cv::Ptr<_Tp2>&), const std::string&)'
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:4024: error:   but 1 required
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:4033: error: redefinition of `void cv::AlgorithmInfo::addParam(cv::Algorithm&, const char*, cv::Ptr<_Tp2>&, bool, cv::Ptr<_Tp2> (cv::Algorithm::*)(), void (cv::Algorithm::*)(const cv::Ptr<_Tp2>&), const std::string&)'
D:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:4024: error: `void cv::AlgorithmInfo::addParam(cv::Algorithm&, const char*, cv::Ptr<_Tp2>&, bool, cv::Ptr<_Tp2> (cv::Algorithm::*)(), void (cv::Algorithm::*)(const cv::Ptr<_Tp2>&), const std::string&)' previously declared here
```

Edit:
there is my code.

```
include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main (int, char**) 
{
  cv::VideoCapture camera(1); 
  if(!camera.isOpened())
  {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not open camera" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  cv::namedWindow("Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  while(1)
  {
    cv::Mat frame;
    camera >> frame;
    cv::imshow("Webcam", frame);
    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) 
    {
        imwrite("test.jpg", frame);
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Execution terminated

Can you please help me on this? Please.
Thanks.

Comment: could you please post your code also?

Comment: Do not use old headers. Try to include only `<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>`. You'll be able to get it working.

Comment: It still has the error. Is there something wrong with my compiler setting?

Comment: I see two issues: 1) don't use paths that contain spaces with gcc: _VS Projects_ and 2) you try to link with opencv lib that is built with Visual Studio 2012: L"D:\opencv\build\x86\ _vc12_ \lib" - and you try to build your application with a windows gcc port, most likely MinGW.

Comment: what lib should i use? I did follow this tutorial [link]http://talkwithimage.blogspot.com/2013/01/linking-open-cv-243-in-dev-c-52.html